# What type of insect is it?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I've found this insect in my apartment and I don't know it could be bed bug or not. Could it be hazardous and what are the ways for getting rid of it?
[image]

Comment: @PolypipeWrangler Answers should be in answers, not in comments.

Comment: Approximately where in the world are you? if you can, a close up photo would be useful.